# Negation of an "and" of two conditions

Tags: logic

Let $k_2, k_3, k_4, k_5 > 0$ in the reals and $0 \leq m < 1$.

Consider the set $S = \{k_4/k_5 > m \text{  AND } k_2 > k_3\}$. Which is the complement of $S$?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of set is that? Are its elements numbers, pairs, quartets?

Comment: De Morgan's laws:$$\lnot(a\land b)=\lnot a\lor\lnot b$$$$\lnot(a\lor b)=\lnot a\land\lnot b$$

Comment: They are all real numbers :)

Answer (score 2):

The complement of "A and B" is "(Not A) or (Not B)": to avoid the and-condition being true, it must be the case that at least one of its two conditions fails.

To have the condition $k_4/k_5>m$ fail, you need $k_4/k_5\leq m$.  To have the condition $k_2>k_3$ fail, you need $k_2\leq k_3$.

So, the complement of $S$ is $\{(k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5)\mid \frac{k_4}{k_5}\leq m\text{ or }k_2\leq k_3\}$.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{k_4}{k_5}\le m \quad\text{OR}\quad k_2\le k_3$

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer